# Save an array inside a variable store inside another variable

Tags: matlab

```
a=1:500; 

name='b'
```

How can I store my array **'a'** into variable **'b'**?

Comment: You can do this with `eval`, but you probably don't want to.  Code with `eval` is often extremely hard to read and maintain.  Consider describing your top-level problem for better suggestions.

Comment: I'd avoid it, and store your stuff in a struct or cell array instead.